# java why is long value in if statement validated wrong

Tags: java, validation, long-integer

In the below code the `if` statement evaluates to `true` but i can see its `false`.
Clearly there is a logic here to explain this but i cannot remember it.
2 movies showing the phenomenology:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFcRfPErfik
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEC04-kLQBE

The line "holderCompleated.textInfo.setT..." will run even do diffHours==1
look at the picture, `diffHours`=1 and Expression windows show `false`

[image]

a summery for this question could be:
(dont be affraid to ask even the the silliest question :))

here's a picture when i enter the `if statment`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the if statement will be taken *on this iteration*?

Comment: So you're saying "holderCompleated..." is executed even if the debugger shows that "diffHours > 1" if false?

Comment: yes that exactly what happen, look at the picture, added one more. to bad one cannot add a short movie instead of pictures to show it. And yes i did a Clean project in eclipse to rule out inconsistencies

Comment: Do you spawn additional threads in your application?

Comment: Have you tried changing `int` 1 to `long` 1? -> `if(diffHours > 1L) { ...`

Comment: interesting , no i dont that code is inside the @Override getView function for BaseAdapter. The main thread is halted on the breakpoint, i think..

Comment: yes, same result -"Have you tried changing int 1 to 1L?"

Comment: As this actually cannot happen you should insert some System.out.print statements to verify the state of the variables. Perhaps there is something wrong with the debugger.

Comment: Good ide will do, LogCat will do, lets see what happen

Comment: something strange going on. im adding the Log.d(TAG,... inside the if statement and the debugger is stepping over it not running the line. Also have a Log.d(TAG,.. just before the if statement and that one is ok.

Comment: Did you restart the emulator?

Comment: Look at the debugger after it steps into the if block, the *diffHours > 1* expression cannot evaluate.

Comment: Show us the value of diffHours inside the if block.

Comment: the  Log.d(TAG..  inside the if statement is exucuted when i step debug but LogCat show nothing, it's like debugger running on the wrong line

Comment: Can you actually see the result of that "setText" line being executed? As far as I understand this, it's the debugger's fault.

Comment: inside the if i have two lines first setText line then the Log.d(TAG,.... On debug step entering the if, it jumps to Log.d(TAG,... (it jumps over the settext). It looks like it only executing the Log.d(TAG,... but the LogCat show nothing. I just deleted the entire java file and recreated it after restart eclipse. Same thing happen. will rename it now lets see

Comment: So the code inside the if statement isn't executed. The debugger says so, however. I'd recommend filing an eclipse bug report...

Comment: added a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEC04-kLQBE

Comment: just filed a bugreport doe im aware it could be locally related, but who knows

Comment: Have you killed adb as well? That clearly shows the usual signs of old code being executed (see Puce's post).

Comment: i have restarted computer a few times but not explicitly kill adb. will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> something strange going on. im adding the Log.d(TAG,... inside the if statement and the debugger is stepping over it. Also have a Log.d(TAG,.. just before the if statement and that one is ok.

Maybe the clean-up didn't work and you're running some old code. Did you try to restart Eclipse? And then maybe delete and re-import some projects?

This would also explain why you see the debugger entering the if statement: it isn't! The running code is just not synchronized with the source code.

Comment: Yeah, most likely the program did not recompile and you're executing old code.

Comment: just restarted computer and close open project and did clean. Same thing happen. Also the Log.d(TAG.. inside if statement is executed when i step debug but no entry in LogCat. Think i need to flush some cache somewhere because debugger is having a bad day. Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 1 Build id: 20110916-0149